# preg_replace - remove table row if the second cell is empty

Tags: php, replace

I have the following HTML code that is generated via a php script:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Color</strong></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Size</strong></td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the second cell of each row is empty remove the row, so the result will be this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Size</strong></td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Probably best using Javascript/jQuery with it's DOM parsing, rather than with regular expression matching. If your table only has two columns, it would be very easy. Or check the value when PHP outputs it (if possible) and simple skip the output if it's empty.

Comment: Matthew, I'm not sure how I can do that. The code is generated by Contact Form 7 (WP plugin). I want to remove the empty tags with preg_replace using a function in functions.php (like here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-how-to-do-away-with-blank-lines-in-email-for-unfilled-form-items?replies=6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use regexp (assuming you want to modify HTML you loaded from external source), it's possible to do this with [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
<?php
$html = '<html><body><table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Color</strong></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Size</strong></td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach( $xpath->query('//table/tr') as $tr){
    $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
    // You should check whether <tr> has two <td>s or is it error

    echo $tds->item(0)->nodeValue . " = " . $tds->item(1)->nodeValue . "<br/>";

    if( !$tds->item(1)->nodeValue){
        $tr->parentNode->removeChild($tr);
    }
}

echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML()) . "</pre>";
```

Working [fiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uek-60j). Or you can use little more complex `xPath` and do it even more elegant:

```
foreach( $xpath->query('//table/tr[td[2][not(text())]]') as $tr){
    $tr->parentNode->removeChild($tr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
<table>
<?php if($color){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Color</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $color ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($size){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Size</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $size ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```